# How can I check the state of gpu when using Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to know the state of the gpu used by mine when using Colab.

I tried

```
!nivdia-smi
```

while it can not work along with my program so It shows no process.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried but there are ways to ssh into colab so you can run nvidia-smi on ssh and run your code on regular colab cell.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the menu "Runtime" >> "Manage Session".

I think there's the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

change
`!nivdia-smi`
to
`!nvidia-smi`